# Tagged value validation through C# add-ins in Enterprise Architect

Tags: c#, add-in, enterprise-architect

I am writing a C# Add-in Enterprise Architect to validate tagged value because a default 0 appears in the tagged value space when I use tagged value of Type=Integer.
I have given tagged value of Type=String and validating the user entered value. I am using the following code.

```
    public bool EA_OnNotifyContextItemModified(EA.Repository Repository, string GUID, EA.ObjectType ot)
        {


                string test_value;
                bool isInteger;
                int integer_converted;
                if (ot == EA.ObjectType.otElement)
                {

                        EA.Element element = (EA.Element)Repository.GetElementByGuid(GUID);
                        EA.TaggedValue tag = element.TaggedValues.GetByName("MAX-BASE-TYPE-SIZE");
                        test_value = tag.Value;
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(test_value))
                        {
                            Session.Repository.WriteOutput("EA", "Enter any Value", 1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            isInteger = int.TryParse(test_value, out integer_converted);
                            if (isInteger == false)
                            {

                                string empty = " ";
                                tag.Value = empty;
                                tag.Update();
                                Session.Repository.WriteOutput("EA", "Enter Integer Value" + " " + tag.Name + ":" + "", 1);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }


            return true; 
}
```

The problem is,the replacement of invalid tagged value with empty string happens only when I close the element properties window and reopen the element.

How to view  the  tagged value updated with empty string when I move the cursor to the next tagged value of the element itself instead of closing and reopening the element everytime.

Kindly Help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are building an addin why sticking to EA property window..? Build a simple form of your own for adding tagged values to an element so you Can easily validate too..!

Comment: I need to have tagged values of type=RefGUID ,RefGUIDList for this element that's why I am trying to validate the values

Comment: you can get all thoses values even in your custom window na.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no elegant solution. You need to refresh the model view and show the element in the browser again like (pseudo code):

```
repository.RefreshModelView(element.PackageID)
repository.ShowInProjectView(element)
```

Comment: @Kilian when I use RefreshModelView(element.PackageID) EA stops working sometimes.I tired using only ShowInProjectView(element) it works only for the first time when element is dragged and dropped and stops working on changing tagged value for the next time..Kindly help..

Comment: I get a windows "Enterprise Architect-UML Development Tool has stopped working" pop-up message

Comment: Are you using V13?

Comment: No,I am using V12.1

Comment: Those are rather basic methods and it's unlikely to suspect they would not work. In such cases I'd suspect a programming error in the add-in. Try with just the above commented. Also place debug prints to EA's console on entry and exit of your add-in.